# Remove letter duplicates that are in a row

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching, spell-checking

Looking for a fast way to limit duplicates to a max of 2 when they occur next to each other.

For example: `jeeeeeeeep` => `['jep','jeep']`

Looking for suggestions in python but happy to see an example in anything - not difficult to switch.

Thanks for any assistance!

EDIT: <s>English doesn't have any (or many) consonants (same letter) in a row right? Lets limit this so no duplicate consonants in a row and up to two vowels in a row</s>

EDIT2: I'm silly (hey that word has two consonants), just checking all letters, limiting duplicate letters that are next to each other to two.

Comment: At what point in the program are you trying to limit this?  As the user inputs something or afterwards?  What does the input look like?  Just a single word or an entire string with the possibility of many matches?

Comment: What should the output be for "jjjjeeeeppppp"?

Comment: @elmugrat - this is basically going into a spell checker but its not on-the-fly so I'd fix it after pressing "enter"

@Ned Now that you mention it I'd like limit vowels to two and consonants to one (that holds true for english, right?) so output would still be ['jep', 'jeep'] good point though, that spec needed to be seen

Comment: @jphenow:  That should be OK for vowels, but don't forget about words like "correct" or "rabbit" that have more than one of the same consonant in a row.

Comment: English has plenty of double-consonants. `Better` check yourself, lol.

Comment: Ah damn. Ha, I was so excited for a moment - that would make this run much quicker.

Comment: I can't think of any english word with 3 duplicate letters in a row (but then there are many, many words out there - someone go check some dict?), but for example in German the same does not hold true.

Comment: I'd suggest checking that bookkeeper works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution using `groupby`. I've left it up to you which characters you want to be able to repeat (defaults to vowels only though):

```
from itertools import groupby

def find_dub_strs(mystring):
    grp = groupby(mystring)
    seq = [(k, len(list(g)) >= 2) for k, g in grp]
    allowed = ('aeioupt')
    return rec_dubz('', seq, allowed=allowed)

def rec_dubz(prev, seq, allowed='aeiou'):
    if not seq:
        return [prev]
    solutions = rec_dubz(prev + seq[0][0], seq[1:], allowed=allowed)
    if seq[0][0] in allowed and seq[0][1]:
        solutions += rec_dubz(prev + seq[0][0] * 2, seq[1:], allowed=allowed)
    return solutions
```

This is really just a heuristically pruned depth-first search into your "solution space" of possible words. The heuristic is that we only allow a single repeat at a time, and only if it is a valid repeatable letter. You should end up with 2**n words at the end, where n is he number times an "allowed" character was repeated in your string.

```
>>> find_dub_strs('jeeeeeep')
['jep', 'jeep']
>>> find_dub_strs('jeeeeeeppp')
['jep', 'jepp', 'jeep', 'jeepp']
>>> find_dub_strs('jeeeeeeppphhhht')
['jepht', 'jeppht', 'jeepht', 'jeeppht']
```

Comment: See my revised post - refined the rules. Try limiting vowels to two in a row and no dupes in a row otherwise. Make sense?

Comment: @jphenow: And how about numbers? He put 1111 what if the text contains a number that accidentally has doubles or even more repetitions in a row? Consider telephone numbers that would be wrong in that case.

Comment: Not worried about numbers, but redacting the statement about consonants, just worried about all letters

Comment: This is fantastic. I'll give this one a shot when I get back to my computer at home - stupid internship office doesn't allow ssh out...

Comment: @jphenow: No prob, thanks for giving me a real computer science problem to solve instead of "how 2 make matricks in python??!?!".

Comment: Lulz, yea I know what you mean, thanks for the interest! I'm working on a big edit on the http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html, it seems to hate going past two edits. I think some optimization and making a little assumption we can speed it up and make it handle more issue.

Comment: @jphenow: btw did you ever try it? I'd love to see how your work in progress / final product comes along.

Comment: Yup your methods work fantastically! I've mostly trimmed the fat - I really only need to correct for caps, duplicate letters, and misspelled vowels. Only problem now is that anything more than maybe 2 vowel errors and it takes up to 5 seconds. So going to take some pondering. I'll post on github as a I get closer though and I'll maybe re-add more error-correction

Comment: @machine You were hoping to see a closer-to-final product? https://github.com/jphenow/Spellcheck It's not quite persig's, because it assumes there'll be less errors, and I tried to limit duplicates. Not entirely sure how much I love it, but I was going to continue picking at it here and there.

Answer (score 1):

use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1\1+', r'\1\1', 'jeeeep')
'jeep'
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for a single character using `groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'jeeeeeeeep'
>>> ''.join(c for c, unused in groupby(s))
'jep'
```

And the one for maximum of two characters:

```
''.join(''.join(list(group)[:2]) for unused, group in groupby(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Sh+Perl solution, I'm afraid I don't know Python:

```
echo jjjjeeeeeeeeppppp | perl -ne 's/(.)\1+/\1\1/g; print $_;'
```

The key is the regex that finds `(.)\1+` and replaces it by `\1\1`, globally.

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expressions along with a key press event!

Comment: I don't think he wants to limit the input from a keyboard.